# C#, read string from file to be used in JsonConvert.Deserialize method

Tags: c#, serialization, file-io, json.net, deserialization

I was using const string variables to store some serialized json objects in my C# code, such as:

```
private const string response = "{\"Category\":\"Cat1\",\"Culture\":\"en-US\",\"Members\":1,\"Products\":[10,1],\"Address\":\"street\"\"SecondCulture\":\"es-ES\"}" ;

JObject convertedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);
```

It works fine. Now, when I move this string into a '.txt' file, and read it using:

```
string response = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

it fails, returning a System.InvalidCastException.
How should I store/read this string in '.txt' file to work like the const string variable case?

Comment: Do you have the backslashes in your file as well? You should leave them out.

Comment: @Stephen The files are big, should I need to remove the backslashes in each one of them? any other way?

Comment: The backslashes are escape characters in a C# string. They're not needed (and even hurt) when they're in your file. If you can't remove them from your file, remove them from the string after reading the file and before the call to DeserializeObject